# Have TextView scale its font size to fill parent?

Tags: android

Is there a way to have a TextView pick a font size such that it fills whatever space it has available? For example:

```
<LinearLayout
  layout_width="fill_parent"
  layout_height="50dip" >

  <TextView
    layout_width="fill_parent"
    layout_height="fill_parent"
    textSize="scale?" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can post the code of what you created?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is not built in font scaling in a `TextView`.  You could overload the `onDraw()` method in a child of `TextView`, but `TextView` does not support scaling the text automatically.

Take a look at this other [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596452/android-how-to-scale-resize-text-to-fit-a-textview)

Comment: Ok, yeah I just had to write something myelf, bummer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to update, from API 26 (Android 8.0) TextViews has an attribute to scale text on horizontal and vertical axes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Check it at [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

As in the answer Nick Campion quoted, I used a loop and a static layout to iterate to the correct size. My requirements were to fit the width and use no more than one line (no ellipses):

```
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 2) {
       layout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, w, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, true);
        i = layout.getLineCount();
        textSize += 2;
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize*0.95f);
```

Comment: This method can cause the top of the text to be clipped off if the textview isn't tall enough.