# Resize item of itemview

Tags: android, listview

In a listview, every item has the same heigth but if every item has a textview it is possible that some item won't fit its text in its textview so how can I resize each item so all text would be readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. By default a TextView parameter android:singleLine is false. It means that in case of huge text it will split on several rows. If it's good for you, then do nothing.
In other case you can use an autoscale textview from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596452/android-how-to-scale-resize-text-to-fit-a-textview)

Comment: Your first solution was fine. Thanks!