# Auto Adjust Textview Android

Tags: android

I finally found the code to resize the text based on the height of the textview.[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082359/how-to-auto-adjust-text-size-on-a-multi-line-textview-according-to-the-view-max), but i am not getting how to pass the text in this function,my text is cmoing from another intent

```
public int getHeightOfMultiLineText(String text,int textSize, int maxWidth) {
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        int index = 0;
        int linecount = 0;
        while(index < text.length()) {
            index += paint.breakText(text,index,text.length(),true,maxWidth,null);
            linecount++;
        }

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds("Yy", 0, 2, bounds);
        // obtain space between lines
        double lineSpacing = Math.max(0,((linecount - 1) * bounds.height()*0.25)); 

        return (int)Math.floor(lineSpacing + linecount * bounds.height());

    }
```

Comment: save the text in String and passed to getHeightofMultiLineText(ur_string_text,12,10);

Comment: are u getting error or something?

Comment: how to pass to tv.setText(receivingdata); to this function??

Comment: hey Instantiate textview in function and then set text isnt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can get the text of TextView as String using `urTextView.getText().toString()`

```
TextView urTextView;
String text = urTextView.getText().toString();

int textSize = 100;
int maxHeight = 50;
while(getHeightOfMultiLineText(text,textSize,maxWidth) > maxHeight)
    textSize--;
```

This should work.

Comment: i am getting data like this tv.setText(receivingdata); how to pass to function

Comment: after receiving data, do `String text = tv.getText().toString();` and pass to function.

Comment: then i have to remove tv.setText(receivingdata);

Comment: no, you won't have to. the text is set in the textview tv. All you have to do now is to use this text and change its size. So just add what I have posted, and then check.

Comment: if i am fixed the textview size in xml suppose 50,then it is setting the text to 50 not checking the 
int textSize = 100;,i am calling this function in main()?

Comment: This function should be called onCreate()... what do you mean by main()... this is android coding

Comment: fucntion is not properly working,giving the same result with or without fuction,need help