# How i can show all the paragraph with large amount of text in Animation?

Tags: android

I want show all text in `Animation` that my text is(for example):

> "Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print,
>   and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups."

but i can see only `"Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly"` in `animation` when program runs, or if i turn the device: "Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic," that mean can see only one line.

**I used this code:**

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMarqToRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1" />
```

but I'm still searching.

Comment: You are limiting the lines with `android:maxLines="1"`? Thats why it only shows text until the width of the control is reached. Remove the maxlines and add text-wrapping or line-wrapping.

Comment: remove the line `android:maxLIne="1"`
For a large amount of Text listView or RecyclerView is always recommended. TextView is slow for rendering large text.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16672131/8089770

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

> Remove Max line 1.

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textViewMarqToRight"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

You can also try :  `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: Thanks for your response.Unfortunately that didn't work for me!