# autofit 2-textview size in android

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a relative layout and in that i have 2 TextView. I want to adjust the size of both textview as per the user screen size, means if the user has screen small then both, textview will adjust there textsize into half of the screensize so that they both could fully fill screen by width.

Like this:

[image]

there are 2 Textview in images getting adjust as per screensize to fit the width.

Comment: So here u got [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596452/how-to-scale-resize-text-to-fit-a-textview) in a few ways.

Comment: @Januszj. It works for single textview i wants to use 2 textview in single line and wants to adjust them as per screensize